# GARCH parameters sum to greater than one

Tags: garch

I am applying GARCH(1,1) to a time series but my parameters sum to greater than one, so that volatility explodes over time. What does this mean, is my series a series than simply can't be modelled by GARCH, or maybe that that $(p,q)=(1,1)$ is inadequate?

If $\{a_t\}$ is a GARCH process then $\{a_t^2\}$ is an ARMA process; if I try R's `auto.arima` function (package "forecast"), it actually suggests that ARMA(1,1,2) would be best.

So, should I use some other variant of GARCH (IGARCH?), or what's going on?

Comment: [Here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/156215/modelling-time-varying-volatility-when-garch1-1-coefficients-sum-to-value-grea) is a related question.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately no one's answered it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will assume that your conditional mean model is well specified. However, weird patterns in the conditional variance equation might very well be due to a poor conditional mean specification. I suggest to make sure you have an adequate model for the conditional mean before going for any exotic conditional variance models.

A GARCH process with coefficients summing up to more than one is not completely implaussible, but certainly it is not very appealing. So what are the alternatives?

> is my series a series than simply can't be modelled by GARCH <...> ?

Coefficients of GARCH(1,1) summing up to more than one is an indication that a stationary GARCH$(r,s)$ model is unlikely to fit the data well. However, there is a great variety of GARCH model versions, so you do not have to lose hope. See, for example, [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/156215/modelling-time-varying-volatility-when-garch1-1-coefficients-sum-to-value-grea) and the link to the survey paper there.

If the conditional variance seems to be increasing deterministically (e.g. with a linear trend), you could include a deterministic trend as an exogenous variable in the GARCH model.

> So, should I use some other variant of GARCH (IGARCH?) <...> ?

If the GARCH(1,1) coefficients summed up to exactly one, using an IGARCH model would be a natural choice. However, your parameters sum to more than one; hence, IGARCH is not that natural (although more plausible than a stationary GARCH).